# Bugs in conditional structure in a newcommand definition with optional arguments

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments, arguments

I am trying to create a new command for add a caption and/or the label to an equation. The not optional parameter is for the text of the equation and first optional parameter is for the label, the second one for the caption. I wrote this code

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty,textfont={bf,it}} 

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myeq}{ O{} O{} m }{
    %\newcommand{\myeq}[3][]{

    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{   
        %IF CAPTION {#2} IS EMPTY
        \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:#1}
        {(!!) #3}
        \end{equation}
        %\vspace{-1em}
    }{
        %IF CAPTION {#2} IS NOT EMPTY
        \begingroup
        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} 
        \begin{mycapequ}[H]
            \begin{equation}
            \label{eq:#1}
            {(!) #3}
            \end{equation}
            \caption{{#2}}
        \end{mycapequ}
        \endgroup

    }
}


\begin{document}

    \myeq[][Forma finita di Eulero]{U\left(S,V,N\right)=TS-pV+\mu N}
    text    
    \myeq[][]{\sideset{_{(ir)rev}}{}\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T}\le 0}
    text
\end{document}
```

but the command does not work properly, infact I expect that was shown {(!!) #3} and not {(!) #3} in the second case:
 [image]
The possible usages I have thought are these:

```
 1. \myeq{\vec{F}=m*\vec{a}} 
 2. \myeq[labe1][]{\vec{F}=m*\vec{a}}
 2. \myeq[][2nd Newton's Law]{\vec{F}=m*\vec{a}} 
 3. \myeq[labe1][2nd Newton's Law]{\vec{F}=m*\vec{a}}
```

Comment: You don't check whether the label is empty. Why that?

Comment: you have not shown the use or the error you got, but `\newcommand` can only define commands with one optional argument so the usage is `\myeq{caption}{equation}` or `\myeq[label]{caption}{equation}` your description appeared to imply you are using it as if it had two optional arguments

Comment: Also, what is the definition of `\ifemptyarg`? Please provide a complete minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` being as minimal as possible to recreate your issue.

Comment: In my experience, there is a difference between `\empty` and `\@empty`, and `[] ` is the same as `\@empty`.  I usually set \empty as the default value so that `\ifx\empty#1\relax` will work.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I usually set `[]` as default and use `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` as test.

Comment: I have improved my post with a complete bad-working implementation of the code I used.

Comment: note also that the blank line at the start of your definition is forcing a paragraph break before the equation, but you should never have a paragraph break before a display (TeX never makes reasonable spacing in that  case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test `\IfNoValueTF` is never true when the argument you refer to is declared as `O`, but only with `o`.

I suggest a change in syntax, because two optional arguments in a row are difficult to manage. Moreover, your argument `#1` is assumed to be not empty, given the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption,float}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty,textfont={bf,it}} 

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myeq}{ o m o }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        %IF CAPTION {#3} IS EMPTY
        \begin{equation}
        \IfValueT{#1}{\label{eq:#1}}
        #2
        \end{equation}
    }{%
        %IF CAPTION {#3} IS NOT EMPTY
        \begin{mycapequ}[H]
        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
        \begin{equation}
        \IfValueT{#1}{\label{eq:#1}}
        #2
        \end{equation}
        \caption{{#3}}
        \end{mycapequ}
    }
}


\begin{document}

\myeq{U\left(S,V,N\right)=TS-pV+\mu N}[Forma finita di Eulero]
text
\myeq[y]{\sideset{_{(ir)rev}}{}\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T}\le 0}
text and reference~\ref{eq:y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd prefer something like

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myeq}{ o m o }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
        %IF CAPTION {#3} IS EMPTY
        \begin{equation}
        \IfValueT{#1}{\label{eq:#1}}
        #2
        \end{equation}
    }{%
        %IF CAPTION {#3} IS NOT EMPTY
        \begin{gather}
        \IfValueT{#1}{\label{eq:#1}}
        #2\\
        \textbf{\itshape #3}\notag
        \end{gather}
    }
}


\begin{document}

text
\myeq{U\left(S,V,N\right)=TS-pV+\mu N}[Forma finita di Eulero]
text
\myeq[y]{\sideset{_{(ir)rev}}{}\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T}\le 0}
text and reference~\ref{eq:y}

\end{document}
```

so you have no float problem.